# Site certificate has expired for docs.sencha.com

Tags: extjs

The certificate for your docs.sencha.com site has expired:

[image: Expired certificate]

As a result, some pages, particularly those containing Fiddle examples, are broken:

[image: Broken Fiddles]

I just thought it best to let you know.

Comment: It appears they've fixed the issue... although their private npm repo is still having issues with the cert.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has fixed and if someone is having an issue then login again on support portal and then try to login on npm repo.

Comment: I was having issues with the private node repo when using `https`, but using `http` instead works... not sure if that's still an issue, but maybe something y'all want to check on?